# CSV file not loading properly

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/CSV/film.csv" 
AS row
CREATE (:Film {film_id: row.film_id, title: row.title, description: row.description, 
release_year: row.release_year, language_id: row.language_id, original_language_id: row.original_language_id,
rental_duration: row.rental_duration, rental_rate: row.rental_rate, length: row.length, replacement_cost: row.replacement_cost, rating: row.rating, 
special_features: row.special_features, last_update: row.last_update});

I wrote this query in NEO4J. after execution it diplayed me with

"*Added 500 labels, created 500 nodes, returned 0 rows in 1709 ms"*

but it isn't displaying properties of the nodes! I have no idea why!

P.S: One line of csv file along with header is:

"row.film_id,row.title,row.description,row.release_year,row.language_id,row.original_language_id,row.rental_duration,row.rental_rate,row.length,row.replacement_cost,row.rating,row.special_features,row.last_update
"1","ACADEMY DINOSAUR","A Epic Drama of a Feminist And a Mad Scientist who must Battle a Teacher in The Canadian Rockies","2006","1","N,"6","0.99","86","20.99","PG","Deleted Scenes,Behind the Scenes","2006-02-15 05:03:42" "

Please help me, I've got an assignment. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `row.` prefix in the header line of your csv in all columns. The `row` in your `LOAD CSV` if the iteration variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do as Stefan suggests or tweak your query to take the actual field names into account:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/CSV/film.csv" AS row 
CREATE (:Film {film_id: row.`row.film_id`, title: `row.row.title`});
```

And so on...